# Checking if borders of layers match using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-10.5

I have two shapefiles which are made out of polygons within one city.

- Districts
- Parishes

I need to check if their borders within the city match- if the parishes are within districts or if they somewhere extend beyond one district to another. The most outter borders match the city border so it's ok.

Is there any way to do so using any ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 or 10.5 toolbox (I have both versions available to me) besides going through it manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after from your description, perhaps a picture would help.. I think you're after a union between parishes and districts and then perhaps a summary statistics with a case field  to identify where a parish exists in multiple districts and then again where a district appears in multiple parishes, this would give you a short list of the ones to look at manually though I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I could be way off-base.

Comment: You should certainly review some documentation on topologies.

Answer (score 1):

Using Select by Location with the spatial relationship of "Are Within" would allow you to select any parishes that are found within a district, even if they share a border. This would not include any parishes that extend past the border of the district. If you want to see specifically parishes that are not within districts, switch the selection.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm

> Are within
>
> To be selected, the geometry of the target feature must fall inside
>   the geometry of the source feature. Selected features and source
>   features can have overlapping boundaries.
>
> For example, using this operator, the state of Montana is selected
>   even if it shares boundaries with the United States